# Prestashop order-checkout shipping country id

Tags: smarty, prestashop, checkout, cart, prestashop-1.6

I'm using Prestashop 1.6 for my e-shop. And I started to make some upgrade.
Now I'm stack with problem to get country name of customer delivery address.

Is anybody know how can I get a country name from step#3(Address) of order-checkout when I'am on step#4("Shipping")?

In what variable ($cart ->…) this type of info placed?

I start to change order-carrier.tpl and add 
`<input type="hidden" value="{$cart->id_address_delivery}"/>` Result is I get some number. I didn't find info what this number point to.

```
<div class="delivery_option_price">
<input type="hidden" value="{$cart->id_address_delivery}"/>
{if $option.total_price_with_tax && !$option.is_free && (!isset($free_shipping) || (isset($free_shipping) && !$free_shipping))}
    {if $use_taxes == 1}
        {if $priceDisplay == 1}
            {convertPrice price=$option.total_price_without_tax}{if $display_tax_label} {l s='(tax excl.)'}{/if}
        {else}
            {convertPrice price=$option.total_price_with_tax}{if $display_tax_label} {l s='(tax incl.)'}{/if}
        {/if}
    {else}
        {convertPrice price=$option.total_price_without_tax}
    {/if}
{else}
    {l s='Free'}
```

Thanks

Comment: share the code and error /log for it?

Comment: thanks Shravan Yadav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Prestashop doesn't keep in session the whole customer addresses for performance purpose, but it keeps a reference using the $cart->id_address_delivery and $cart->id_address_invoice properties.
Those two properties will have the id of the address saved on the 
**ps_address**
table, so if you want to retrieve all the information of an address all you have to do is to create a `new Address()` object with the given id.
We should perform this action inside the Controller, precisely the ParentOrderController where the checkout functionality takes palce and the function we are looking for should be _assignCarrier(). 
([Please remember to extend the controller functionality with the override feature Prestashop offers, to avoid un-upgradable code.](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Controllers+within+PrestaShop#ControllerswithinPrestaShop-Overridingacontroller))

Inside the _assignCarrier() function we will create our address object and then get the country name by this:

```
//create an address object by retrieving the id from the current cart.
$address = new Address($this->context->cart->id_address_delivery);
//now the country name will now be in the "$address->country" field so if you want to pass it to your smarty template use:
$this->context->smarty->assign('country_name', $address->country);
```

finally we have made our country name available to our template so we just need to show it, your code inside the template become:

```
<div class="delivery_option_price">
<input type="hidden" value="{$country_name}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, for so fast and great explanation. Everything is understood and so comprehensive answer. Exactly what I need. Grazie!